# Object doesn't support this property or method?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to enter letter grades into excel, but when I enter a grade, it comes up with "Error 428, Object doesn't support this property or method." What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Sub HW09()

Dim ng As Integer
Dim v As String

Do

ng = InputBox("Please enter the student's numerical grade.")
    If ng < 0 Then
        ng = 0
    ElseIf ng > 100 Then
        ng = 100
    Else
End If


Cells(c, 2).Value (ng)
c = c + 1

v = InputBox("Would you like to enter another grade? Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no.")
    If v = "N" Then Exit Do

Loop
```

Comment: @sam092 has the answer. I noticed this [in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19085142/1467082) and made sure my answer avoided that error.  Also, you can do simply: `If MsgBox("Would you like to enter another grade?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Do` instead of relying on the `InputBox` and clunky user-input of a letter/string :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
Cells(c, 2).Value = ng
```

If you enter letters like **A,B,C** you should get a **Type Mismatch Error** instead.

Also, I don't see any initialization for `c`